# picard of blown up affine cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be the projective completion of affine cone over $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. We blow up this cone X at the vertex and denote this variety by Y. What is the picard of Y?

I think pic $Y =\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, because Y is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundles over $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: No, it is not. It has a nontrivial map onto an affine variety.

Comment: @abx edited...X be the projective completion of affine cone over ℙ1×ℙ1